# Name dataSet as value from row pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to download stock data from yfinance. I have a ticker list called ticker_list_1 with a bunch of symbols. The structure is:

```py
array(['A', 'AAP', 'AAPL', 'ABB', 'ABBV', 'ABC', 'ABEV', 'ABMD', 'ABNB',....
```

Now I am using the following code to download the data:

```py
i = 0
xrz_data = {}
for i, len in enumerate (ticker_list_1):      
   data = yf.download(ticker_list_1[i], start ="2019-01-01", end="2022-10-20")
   xrz_data[i] = data
   i=i+1
```

The problem I am having is that once downloaded the data is saved as xrz_data. I can access a specific dataset through the code `xrz_data[I]` with the corresponding number. However I want to be able to access the data through xrz_data[tickername].

How can I achieve this ?

I have tried using `xrz_data[i].values = data` which gives me the error KeyError: 0

EDIT:
Here is the current output of the for loop:

```
    {0:                   Open        High         Low       Close   Adj Close  \
     Date                                                                     
     2018-12-31   66.339996   67.480003   66.339996   67.459999   65.660202   
     2019-01-02   66.500000   66.570000   65.300003   65.690002   63.937435   
     2019-01-03   65.529999   65.779999   62.000000   63.270000   61.582008   
     2019-01-04   64.089996   65.949997   64.089996   65.459999   63.713589   
     2019-01-07   65.639999   67.430000   65.610001   66.849998   65.066483   
     ...                ...         ...         ...         ...         ...   
     2022-10-13  123.000000  128.830002  122.349998  127.900002  127.900002   
     2022-10-14  129.000000  130.220001  125.470001  125.699997  125.699997   
     2022-10-17  127.379997  131.089996  127.379997  130.559998  130.559998   
     2022-10-18  133.919998  134.679993  131.199997  132.300003  132.300003   
     2022-10-19  130.110001  130.270004  127.239998  128.960007  128.960007
[959 rows x 6 columns],

     1:                   Open        High         Low       Close   Adj Close  \
     Date                                                                     
     2018-12-31  156.050003  157.679993  154.990005  157.460007  149.844055   
     2019-01-02  156.160004  159.919998  153.820007  157.919998  150.281815   
    ........
```

My desired output would be:

```
 AAP:                   Open        High         Low       Close   Adj Close  \
 Date                                                                     
 2018-12-31  156.050003  157.679993  154.990005  157.460007  149.844055   
 2019-01-02  156.160004  159.919998  153.820007  157.919998  150.281815   
........
```

Comment: what is the variable `len` is for?

Comment: From my understanding len allows me to loop through the array length. However this might be redundant. 
Either way the for loop works perfectly as is. the only problem I have is that the different datasets in xrz data are named 0,1,2,3,4 were I would like them to be named A, AAP, AAPL, ...etc

Comment: I have also added the output and my desired output. I want to change the numbers to the ticker names so I can access the specific data later on with xrz_data[tickername] instead of xrz_data[number]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out. With the following code I am able to download the data and access specific tickers through f.e. `xrz_data['AAPL‘]`

```
i = 0

xrz_data = {}
for ticker in ticker_list_1:      
    data = yf.download(ticker, start ="2019-01-01", end="2022-10-20")
    xrz_data[ticker] = data
```